# Least squares standard result: why toy example fails?

Tags: probability, examples-counterexamples, least-squares

> $y$ is a random variable, and $x$ is a $(k+1)\times 1$ random vector:
>   $$
> x=(1,x_1,\ldots,x_k)'.
> $$
>   I recall that a nonrandom $1\times(k+1)$ vector $\beta$ that minimizes $E[(y-\beta x)^2]$ is given by
>   $$
> \hat\beta=E(yx')E(xx')^{-1}.\tag{$*$}
> $$
>   Then I test ($*$) by thinking of the case when $y=\alpha$ for some nonrandom $\alpha$. Clearly, the optimal $\beta$ should be $(\alpha,0,\ldots,0)$ but that's not what ($*$) gives me. What am I missing please?

**Clarification**: At some point I think ($*$) is wrong somehow but for all $\beta$
\begin{align}
E[(y-\beta x)^2]&=E[((\hat\beta-\beta)x+(y-\hat\beta x))^2]\\
&=E[((\hat\beta-\beta)x)^2]+E[(y-\hat\beta x)^2]+2(\hat\beta-\beta)E[x(y-\hat\beta x)].
\end{align}
Since
$$
E[(y-\hat\beta x)x']=E(yx')-E(yx')E(xx')^{-1}E(xx')=0\implies E[x(y-\hat\beta x)]=0
$$
so, $\forall\beta$,
$$
E[(y-\beta x)^2]= E[((\hat\beta-\beta)x)^2]+E[(y-\hat\beta x)^2]\geq E[(y-\hat\beta x)^2]
$$
so ($*$) actually seems alright. Frustratingly, I know these are supposedly to be standard results so why doesn't the simple example above work?

Comment: It seems to me that you are mixing up scalars and vectors. For example, $xx'$ should be a degenerate matrix in general, what do you mean by $\mathsf E(xx')^{-1}$?

Comment: @CaveJohnson If $x=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}$ (i.e. $k=1$) then $E(xx')=\begin{pmatrix}1 & E(x_1) \\ E(x_1) & E(x_1^2)\end{pmatrix}$ which is invertible as long as $\text{Var}(x_1)>0$. More generally, $E(xx')=\text{Var}(x)+E(x)E(x)'$ so it should be invertible.

Comment: But if you mean $(\mathsf E(xx'))^{-1}$, then $\hat\beta=(\alpha,0,\ldots,0)$ is exactly what I get from $(*)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing please?

**Answer**: the toy example does not fail!

Let $z=\begin{pmatrix}z_1 & \cdots & z_k\end{pmatrix}'$ so that $x=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ z\end{pmatrix}$. Then
\begin{align*}
E(\alpha x')E(x x')^{-1}&=\alpha\begin{pmatrix}1 & E(z')\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & E(z')\\ E(z) & E(zz')\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\alpha\begin{pmatrix}1 & E(z')\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1+E(z')[\text{Var}(z)]^{-1}E(z)&-E(z')[\text{Var}(z)]^{-1}\\ -[\text{Var}(z)]^{-1}E(z) & [\text{Var}(z)]^{-1}\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\alpha\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0_{k\times 1}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
which is your expected answer.